# cast all cells of an array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm a begginer in Matlab.
For the first exercise, I want to do some changes on an image. 
I load image as an array. The array is a three dimensial array. All number in array is unsigned and I have to convert them to `int32`. 
I decided to traverse all of array and by `cast` function change it's data type.
now I would like to know is there any simpler way for doing my requirement?
I looked for a solution on the Internet, but I didn't find any thing.

Comment: You mean like [`int32(X)`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int32.html)?

Comment: yes, I meant I want to convert to int32

Comment: Which you can do like I just showed, by simply using `int32(X)` where `X` is a matrix. My comment was also a link to the documentation for `int32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img_uint = imread('C:\myimg.png');
whos img_uint;

img_int32 = int32(img_uint);
whos img_int32;
```